# Portmap and NFS4

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

Is the portmap service required on a ubuntu machine
- when i'm using NFS4 mount only
- when i'm exporting files using NFS4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you only need it to listen on 127.0.0.1. Put `OPTIONS="-i 127.0.0.1"` in `/etc/default/portmap`.